# Exchange vs exchange rates

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms, reversed-synonyms

I suspect this has come up, but after the comments on [Exchanging Albanian Money Into Euros Outside Albania](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/3535/exchanging-albanian-money-into-euros-outside-albania), wondered if we could clarify here.

[exchange](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/exchange) is a synonym for [exchange-rates](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/exchange-rates) - that is, any [exchange](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/exchange) tags get converted into [exchange-rates] tags.  However, they were both separate at one point, even having a tag wiki for [exchange](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/exchange).

When you consider the question at hand, I would have thought that really it has nothing to do with [exchange-rates](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/exchange-rates) - he just wants to [exchange](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/exchange) them.  I briefly considered unsynonymising them, but figured someone may have had a reason for it that I'm missing.

Answer (score 3):

This was a comment but I see there's a meta question so here:

> Hmm "exchange" and "exchange rates" used to be separate. I think it's just another case of a good tag merge but the wrong tag chosen as the main one. @MarkMayo can you flip them please? The more general term should always be the main one.

Comment: Yes, [exchange] should definitely be the main one. **More importantly**, if they really are synonyms, shouldn't the searches for [[exchange](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/exchange)] and [[exchange-rates](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/exchange-rates)] find the exact same questions? I thought this was a bug in the software when first encountering it. If it's because of the tag wikis, can you delete the extra one?

Comment: No the tag wikis don't have effects like that. But if somebody has recently merged or separated the tags there can be delays sorting that stuff out for searches due to the nature of big distributed databases.

Comment: have swapped the pair for now.  Now are we convinced that they *should* be synonyms?

Comment: I think there's only a couple of questions about rates and due their fluctuating nature good questions about them will be rare because most things you would ask about them are "too localized". We can always separate them later if some pressing need arises.